# How to incrementally train a word2vec model with new vocabularies

Tags: python, word2vec

I got a dataset over 40G. The program of my tokenizer is killed due to limited memory, so I try to split my dataset. How can I train the word2vec model incrementally, that is, how can I use separate datasets to train one word2vec model?

My current word2vec code is:

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents, size=150, window=10, min_count=1, workers=10)
model.train(documents,total_examples=len(documents),epochs=epochs)
model.save("./word2vec150d/word2vec_{}.model".format(epochs))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution: use `PathLineSentences`. It is very fast. Incrementally training a word2vec model cannot learn new vocabularies, but `PathLineSentences` can.

```py
from gensim.models.word2vec import PathLineSentences

model = Word2Vec(PathLineSentences(input_dir), size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2, iter=20,sg=1)
```

For single file, use `LineSentences`.

```py
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence

model = Word2Vec(LineSentence(file), size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2, iter=20,sg=1)
...
```

Comment: When I use PathLineSenteces as you suggested, I get this error `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home ...`.

How am I suppose to initialize it if not using a path to a folder?

Comment: @antonio-sesto, you should probably ask about your particular error in a separate question, where you can include enough of your specific code to show what you're trying, and the full multiline traceback info from the error you're seeing.