# Embedding multiword ngram phrases with PathLineSentences in gensim word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have around 82 gzipped files (around 180MB each and 14GB total) where each file contains new line separated sentences. I am thinking of using [PathLineSentences](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.PathLineSentences) from gensim Word2Vec to train word2vec model on the vocabularies. In that way [I do not have to worry about taking all the sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925659/how-to-incrementally-train-a-word2vec-model-with-new-vocabularies) list into the RAM.

Now I also wanted to get the embedding to include multiword phrases. But from the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#embeddings-with-multiword-ngrams), it seems that I need to have an already trained phrase detector an all the sentences I have e.g.

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
# Train a bigram detector.
bigram_transformer = Phrases(all_sentences)
# Apply the trained MWE detector to a corpus, using the result to train a Word2vec model.
model = Word2Vec(bigram_transformer[all_sentences], min_count=1)
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way I can do the Phrase Detection while running the Word2Vec on top of each of the individual files in a streaming manner?
2. If not, is there any way I can do the initial phrase detection in the similar fashion of PathLineSentences, as in doing the phrase detection in a streaming manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gensim `Phrases` class will accept data in the exact same form as `Word2Vec`: an iterable of all the tokenized texts.

You can provide that both as the initial training corpus, then as the corpus to be transformed into paired bigrams.

However, I would highly suggest that you *not* try to do the phrase-combinations in a simultaneous stream as feeding to `Word2Vec`, for both clarity and efficiency reasons.

Instead, do the transformation once, writing the results to a new, single corpus file. Then:

- you can easily review the results of the bigram-combinations
- the pair-by-pair calculations that decide which words will be combined will be done only once, creating a simple corpus of space-delimited tokens. (Otherwise, each of the `epochs + 1` passes done by `Word2Vec will need to repeat the same calculations.)

Roughly that'd look like:

```py
with open('corpus.txt', 'w') as of:
    for phrased_sentence in bigram_transformer[all_sentences]:
        of.write(' '.join(phrased_sentence)
        of.write('\n')
```

(You could instead write to a gzipped file like `corpus.txt.gz` instead, using `GzipFile` or `smart_open`'s gzip functionality, if you'd like.)

Then the new file shows you exact data `Word2Vec` is operating on, and can be fed as a simple corpus - wrapped as an iterable with `LineSentence` or even passed using the `corpus_file` option that can better use more `workers` threads.