# training a Word2Vec model with a lot of data

Tags: python, pandas, gensim

I am using `gensim` to train a `word2vec` model. The problem is that my data is very large (about 10 million documents) so my session is crashing when I try to estimate the model.

Note that I am able to load all the data at once in the RAM in a Pandas dataframe `df`, which looks like:

```
text               id
long long text      1
another long one    2
...                 ...
```

My simple approach is to do the following:

```
tokens = df['text'].str.split(r'[\s]+')
model = Word2Vec(tokens, min_count = 50)
```

However, my session crashed when it tries to create the tokens all at once. Is there a better way to proceed in `gensim`? Like feeding the data line by line?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the crash log so that we can know what caused the crash.

Comment: [Download more RAM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epicegg.downloadmoreram&hl=en_US&gl=US). That said, you probably don't need to generate all tokens for all the text. `.str.split` is not really vectorized anyway, so you can just do a `for` loop and update a global set of tokens.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have access to it. I believe generating all the tokens at once simply fills all the RAM available. But gensim seems to suggest we can use iterables here. The question is how to make it work with my pandas dataframe?

Comment: If so, you can try incremental learning.

Comment: The doc suggests that you can just pass `Word2Vec(df['text'], min_count=50)`?

Comment: no I think these need to be tokenized first unfortunately. PS you must be kidding with download more RAM app eh? :D

Comment: This answer may help you, 40g data step-by-step incremental training model. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925659/how-to-incrementally-train-a-word2vec-model-with-new-vocabularies

Comment: @QuangHoang Which doc suggests that? (You can't; the `Word2Vec` class needs its training texts tokenized, so this suggestion is as useless as your download-ram joke.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over your dataframe row by row, tokenizing just one row at a time. Write each tokenized text to a file in turn, with spaces between the tokens, and a line-end at the end of each text.

You can then use the `LineSentence` utility class in Gensim to provide a read-from-disk iterable corpus to the `Word2Vec` model.

Comment: thank you so much @gojomo. So you confirm that `gensim` needs the data tokenized already, such as `input = [['thank', 'you', 'gojomo'],[this','is','very','nice']]` right? Also, would it be possible to create an iterator from the pandas dataframe? After all, all the data is loaded into the RAM at once... what do you think?

Comment: Yes, it must be tokenized. Yes, you could write an *iterable* object that reads from the dataframe row-by-row - note that a single-pass *iterator* isn't enough. It has to read, tokenize, & yield each row as a list-of-tokens individually, & be restartable for multiple iterations. But as long as you're doing that, it's often a good idea to just write that tokenized, plain-text data to a file – especially if anything more expensive than a simple `.split()` is happening to each string. Once you have that format, you may not need the dataframe in memory at all, freeing space for other steps.